# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi programa de Python revise si una celda está vacía y sumar un punto si no lo está?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, google-colab

Sé que puedo revisar si hay celdas vacías en columnas en general y sé cómo revisar en qué filas hay valores nulos, pero quisiera poder calculcar si una celda dentro de una columna está vacía y guardar el id de esta fila. Mi idea es que si la columna se llama "Materia1" y dentro de esta esté escrito cualquier valor, como "Matematicas", se sume un uno a una variable, que a la vez guarde el nombre del alumno, que si el nombre del alumno ya existe, sólo se sume otro uno.

Estoy trabajando con un dataframe de 62 columnas, y bastantes filas, la idea es saber cuántas materias está cursando un alumno realmente.

Edit:

Sólo he intentado algo como:

```
    projectstat = pd.read_excel("/content/AlumnosyMaterias.xlsx"
    projectstat["Materia1"].value_counts() 
    id_counts = projectstata.groupby(['Alumno'])['Alumno'].count()
    cuentas = id_counts[id_counts>1]
    cuentas 

    # Hice lo anterior para ver más o menos cuantas veces se repetia cada nombre de los alumnos 
    nan_rows = projectstat[projectstat.isnull().any(1)]["Materias1"]
    rows = nan_rows.isnull()
    print(rows)
```

El excel es algo así

| Alumno | Materia1 | Materia2 | Materia 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Patricia | Fisica | Frances |  |
| Lázaro | Matematicas |  | Ciencias P |

Comment: Añade el código que has intentado

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: ¿Existen varias filas para el mismo alumno? Es decir, ¿Podría haber 3-4 líneas con materias para Patricia? Si hay nombres duplicados, ¿Suponemos inmediatamente que son del mismo alumno? O ¿Podría haber dos alumnos con el mismo nombre? ¿Qué se haría en ese caso? Al final ¿Lo único que deseas es contar las celdas que no están vacías para cada alumno?